# Issue With Obfuscar Configuration Skipping Enum Values

Tags: vb.net, enums, obfuscation, obfuscar

I have a class library with an internal logging module which uses an `Enum` at the namespace level to define the log level (Debug, Trace, Error, etc). I use the string conversion of these enumerated values in the logging text. The enum is marked `Friend` (ie, internal, not publically exposed).

When I initially ran obfuscation, the logs were missing the enum descriptions and I eventually found out that Obfuscar was, reasonably, obfuscating the enum values, so I added a `SkipEnum` directive:

```
<Module file="$(InPath)\MyCompany.MyLibrary.dll">
  <SkipEnums type="MyCompany.MyLibrary.Logging.LogLevel" name="*" />
</Module>
```

(**UPDATE**: Corrected `SkipEnum` to `SkipEnums` above. The code I tried had the latter element, so this wasn't the problem.)

This didn't appear to do anything according to the Obfuscar map file:

```
[MyCompany.MyLibrary]MyCompany.MyLibrary.Logging.LogLevel -> [MyCompany.MyLibrary] {unprintable obfuscated name}
{
    MyCompany.MyLibrary.Logging.LogLevel [MyCompany.MyLibrary]MyCompany.MyLibrary.Logging.LogLevel MyCompany.MyLibrary.Logging.LogLevel::Debug -> {unprintable obfuscated name}
    MyCompany.MyLibrary.Logging.LogLevel [MyCompany.MyLibrary]MyCompany.MyLibrary.Logging.LogLevel MyCompany.MyLibrary.Logging.LogLevel::Trace -> {unprintable obfuscated name}
    MyCompany.MyLibrary.Logging.LogLevel [MyCompany.MyLibrary]MyCompany.MyLibrary.Logging.LogLevel MyCompany.MyLibrary.Logging.LogLevel::Info -> {unprintable obfuscated name}
    ...
    MyCompany.MyLibrary.Logging.LogLevel [MyCompany.MyLibrary]MyCompany.MyLibrary.Logging.LogLevel MyCompany.MyLibrary.Logging.LogLevel::Off -> {unprintable obfuscated name}

    System.Int32 [MyCompany.MyLibrary]System.Int32 MyCompany.MyLibrary.Logging.LogLevel::value__ skipped:  special name
}
```

So I tried using `SkipType` with `skipEnums`:

```
<Module file="$(InPath)\MyCompany.MyLibrary.dll">
  <!--SkipType name="MyCompany.MyLibrary.Logging.LogLevel" skipEnums="true" /-->
</Module>
```

This kinda worked; it hid the name of the enum ("LogLevel") but not the enum values themselves.

So then I tried `SkipType` with `skipFields`:

```
<Module file="$(InPath)\MyCompany.MyLibrary.dll">
  <!--SkipType name="MyCompany.MyLibrary.Logging.LogLevel" skipFields="true" /-->
</Module>
```

This worked.

BUT ... when I checked the resulting assembly, the previously hidden/internal  namespace `MyCompany.MyLibrary.Logging` was exposed and I want this to remain hidden.

Is any of this a bug? Am I doing something wrong? Though I think the product is quite good, the doco for Obfuscar is fairly skeletal so I'm having to guess some of this.

Comment: https://github.com/obfuscar/obfuscar/blob/master/Tests/SkipEnumTests.cs You can check examples. There is no option called `SkipEnum`.

Comment: @LexLi I corrected the question content. I had tried using `SkipEnums`, not `SkiEnum`. Had a look through your tests but it didn't really provide an answer.

Comment: The first few test cases showed how to use `<SkipField>`. If you found it too hard to write the proper configuration file, simply use .NET attributes in the source code, https://docs.obfuscar.com/getting-started/configuration.html#exclusion-by-attributes-in-code

Answer (score 0):

SkipEnums should be used in following format:

```
<SkipEnums value="true" />
```

That skips renaming all enumeration type. However, I cannot succeeded to filter by name.